# Convert string to datetime and compare to dates in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a `DateTime` column in my model, currently I'm trying to filter out entries greater than a date represented by a string "2018-04-11 04:03:20":

```
class SomeType(object):
    created_at = Column(DateTime, default=lambda: datetime.utcnow())

beginning_time = datetime.strptime("2018-04-11 04:03:20", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

candidates = session.query(SomeType).filter(SomeType.created_at >= beginning_time).all()
```

The problem is that `candidates` always contain some records that does not meet the criteria. Samples of erronous results:

```
{
    "inspection_name": "lsof check",
    "name": "lsof check",
    "executor": "Susan",
    "created_at": "2018-04-17T11:12:08.000000",
    "score": 43,
    "inspection_groups": "CLM EC",
    "id": "125d932e-293e-469f-8cd2-d08f44bf2ab8",
    "updated_at": "2018-04-17T11:12:23.000000"
},
{
    "inspection_name": "lsof-fake",
    "name": "lsof-fake",
    "executor": "Susan",
    "created_at": "2018-03-21T14:34:19.000000",
    "score": 40,
    "inspection_groups": "CLM EC",
    "id": "1278309f-7dd6-49f4-9d3d-f44097b4baf8",
    "updated_at": "2018-03-21T14:34:21.000000"
},
```

But When I use a date generated by `datetime`:

```
beginning_time = datetime.utcnow()-timedelta(days=2)
```

I can get the exactly correct candidates. Any ideas on how I can do this the right way?

Comment: Please include some example data and samples of erronous results compared to what you expected. In other words produce a [mcve]. What database are you using?

Comment: FYI, your use of `default=lambda: datetime.utcnow()` is unnecessary. Simply pass the `utcnow` function itself: `default=datetime.utcnow` works just as well.

Comment: As for your question: when you generate your datetime from a string, are you taking timezone info into account? You’re likely storing dates in utc but when you construct your beginning time from a string, you may be involving your local timezone, hence the unexpected results

Comment: @ilja-everilä, some example data was in the post, and my database is MySQL

Comment: By example data I mean a sample of data in your database, or in other words something to query against, but what you provided might suffice.

Comment: @daveruinseverything a date object produced by `datetime.strptime(str, format)` has not the `tzinfo` attribute, so I set it with `pytz.timezone('UTC').localize(date)`, but I still get the unexpected results